# How to check if a thread is running in C #?

Tags: c#, multithreading, system

I created a thread in C # 4.0 and would like to know how do I check if it is running?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post your code.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Thread.IsAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) to check to see if a `Thread` is running.

That being said, if you're using C# 4, it's rarely a good idea to make "threads" manually.  You should consider using the TPL and the `Task`/`Task<T>` class, as this provides a much cleaner model to attach work to run after the task completes, pull data out of the operation, etc.

Comment: Is Task now prefered over BackgroundWorker in .NET 4? I've just learned of Task, but doesn't seem to have events to subscribe to like BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @StealthRabbi In general, you can do the same things you would do with BW with tasks.  Continuations and schedulers let you accomplish much of the same concepts.  In C# 5, async/await uses the Task and really makes BW obsolete completely, IMO.  See http://reedcopsey.com/2010/04/19/parallelism-in-net-part-17-think-continuations-not-callbacks/ for info on Task with UI work.

Answer (score 0):

I use Mutex to verify this. Sometimes just verify is Thread is alive with Thread.IsAlive is not safe if you are running on Background.

Try this:

```
private void btnDoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        string nameThread = "testThreadDoSomething";

        var newThread = new Thread(delegate() { this.DoSomething(nameThread); });
        newThread.IsBackground = true;
        newThread.Name = nameThread;
        newThread.Start();

        //Prevent optimization from setting the field before calling Start
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

public void DoSomething(string threadName)
{
    bool ownsMutex;

    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, threadName, out ownsMutex))
    {
        if (ownsMutex)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300000); // 300 seconds

            if (Monitor.TryEnter(this, 300))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Your Source
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string mensagem = "Error : " + e.ToString();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(this);
                }
            }

            //mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```